# How do I determine the actual amount of power my nuclear reactor can provide?

Tags: factorio

I just build my first nuclear reactor. This is quite a bit more complicated than the earlier ways of powering your base, and I'm not sure I properly handled the heat and water distribution in my nuclear power plant. I can look up the theoretical value based on the number of reactors, but that isn't necessarily the actual power production of my non-theoretical plant.

What I'd like to figure out is how much energy my nuclear plant is actually able to provide, but right now I don't consume enough power to fully use the reactor. So the only value I get out of the statistics is how much power I actually use, not how much I can provide with the nuclear plant. And simply consuming more until I can't meet the demand anymore isn't an ideal strategy.

Is there a way to determine the power production capacity of a nuclear plant without simply consuming more energy than it can provide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Water and steam bottlenecks will not become apparent until you actually start using the water and steam. So I don't think you will be able to find out the practical limit without drawing the power.

That said, you do not have to actually use all that power to test the output:

- If you have large banks of accumulators, recharging them provides plenty of load on your grid.

  A single accumulator can draw only 300kW, however, so it will take 134 of them to accommodate a single 40MW reactor (no adjacency bonuses) - not practical if you do not already have large banks of accumulators.

  If you do have enough, simply disconnecting power until they are discharged and then reconnecting it should show you the actual power output of your plant.
- Alternatively, placing a bank of fluid tanks *behind* your steam turbines will allow them to absorb all the excess steam production which can actually reach them.

  Grab a timer, connect the fluid tanks, wait for a time period you're comfortable with, then disconnect them. Each unit of steam has 0.097MJs of energy, so `amount_of_steam * 0.097 / time_in_seconds` will be equal to the excess output of your plant.

  Since this is the excess output, add it to your actual consumption during the period to get the full output.

  (Output capped at the theoretical turbine output, `5.82MW * turbines`).

Answer (score 1):

This is the ratio I use. It isn't 100% accurate, but it's good enough to start with:

**Calculate effective reactors**

Reactors double effectiveness for each full side they share with another active reactor. So to calculate the number of effective reactors: Count the number of partnerships of sides that are 100% shared and multiply by 2 then add the number of reactors.

So if you have 2 that share a side thats (1x2) + 2 = 4 effective reactors.

3 that have neighbour bonus is (2x2) + 3 = 7 effective reactors.

If you have 4, they can be in a line with 3 full joins (3x2) + 4  = 10 effective reactors or in a square with 4 full joins (4x2) + 4 = 12 effective reactors.

**Calculate heat exchangers**

This is easy: Each effective reactor can support around 4 heat exchangers.

**Calculate water pumps**

This is easy too: One water pump can support around 10 heat exchangers.

**Calculate Steam Turbines**

This is easy too: One heat exchanger can support around 2 Steam Turbines

**Summary**

> 1 Effective Reactor
>
> 4 Heat Exchangers
>
> 0.4 Offshore Pumps
>
> 8 Turbines